# how to fill in datatable from selecting checkbox datagridview in form 2 to datagridview in form 1 with dapper in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, dapper

so the code below if the barcode character length is less than 11 then do it manually by selecting checkbox from datagridview in form 2 and then filldatatable to datagridview in form 1. But I haven't succeeded is there something wrong with my code. Please Guide

Thanks

code in form1

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub FillDataTable(iRow As Integer, ByVal Codeproduct As String, Barcode As String, ColorCode As String, Qty As Integer)

        Dim row As DataRow = _myTable.NewRow()
        row("No") = iRow
        row("Codeproduct") = Codeproduct
        row("Barcode") = Barcode
        row("ColorCode") = ColorCode
        row("Qty") = Qty
        _myTable.Rows.Add(row)
    End Sub
 Private Sub BtxtBarcode_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles BtxtBarcode.KeyPress
        Try
            If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
                If BtxtBarcode.Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox("Please enter item barcode.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
                Else
                    If BtxtBarcode.TextLength <= 11 Then
                        GetItemData(BtxtBarcode.Text)
                        Dim iRow As Integer
                        If Grid.RowCount - 1 = 0 Then
                            iRow = 1
                        Else
                            iRow = Convert.ToInt32(Grid.Rows(Grid.RowCount - 2).Cells(0).Value.ToString()) + 1
                        End If
                        Dim Found As Boolean = False
                        Dim newValue As Integer = 1
                        For j = 0 To Me.Grid.Rows.Count - 1
                            If Convert.ToString(Me.Grid.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value) = BtxtBarcode.Text.ToString() Then
                                Found = True

                                If Integer.TryParse(Grid.Rows(j).Cells(4).Value, newValue) Then
                                    newValue += 1
                                Else
                                    newValue = 1
                                End If
                                Grid.Rows(j).Cells(4).Value = newValue.ToString()
                                BtxtBarcode.Clear()
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        If Not Found Then
'below is the filldatatable method code and update code progress
 Dim f2 As New Form2
                            f2.ShowDialog()
                            Dim columntwo = f2.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
                            Dim columnthree = f2.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
                            FillDataTable(iRow, columntwo, _BBarcode, columnthree, newValue)
                            Grid.DataSource = _myTable
                            BtxtBarcode.Clear()
  End If
                    End If
                End If

                End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Stocks
    Public Property Process() As Boolean
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Colorcode() As String
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Qty_Stock() As Integer
End Class
Public Class item
    Public Property No() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Barcode() As String
    Public Property Colorcode() As String
End Class
```

code in form2

```
Public Class Form2
  Private iService As New Itemservice2()
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        DataGridView1.DataSource = iService.Getitem2(Form1.Btxtcodeproduct.Text)
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Itemservice2

    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString()
  Public Function Getitem2(ByVal code As String) As IEnumerable(Of Stocks)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT * FROM Stocks WHERE CodeProduct = '{code}'"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stocks)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Function GetByCodeProductOrBarcode(ByVal code As String) As item
        Dim sql = $"SELECT Items.Barcode,Items.CodeProduct,Stocks.Colorcode,Stocks.Size FROM Items INNER JOIN Stocks ON Items.Barcode = Stocks.Barcode WHERE Items.CodeProduct = '{code}' or Items.Barcode = '{code}'"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of item)(sql).FirstOrDefault()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

[image: result in datagridview19072023]

Desired Result in datagridview in form 1

| No | CodeProduct | Barcode | Colorcode | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KBE 0927 | 03-22164010 | BHTF07KP | 1 |

CODE IN FORM1

```
Public Class Form1
 Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        _myTable = New DataTable
        _myTable.Columns.AddRange({
        New DataColumn("No", GetType(Integer)),
        New DataColumn("Codeproduct", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Barcode", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("ColorCode", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Qty", GetType(Integer))
    })
        Grid.DataSource = _myTable
    End Sub
Private Sub BtxtBarcode_KeyPress(sender As Object,
                                 e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
                                 Handles BtxtBarcode.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
            AddEntry()
        End If
    End Sub
Private Sub AddEntry()
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BtxtBarcode.Text) OrElse
           String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Btxtcodeproduct.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Please enter item barcode or product code...")
            Return
        End If
        Dim productCode = Btxtcodeproduct.Text.Trim()
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim _BBarcode = BtxtBarcode.Text.Trim()
        If _myTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Any() Then
            If BtxtBarcode.TextLength <= 10 Then
                Using frm = New Form2(productCode)
                    If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    End If
                End Using
                row = _myTable.
                    Select($"Codeproduct = '{productCode}'").
                    FirstOrDefault()
            Else
                row = _myTable.
                    Select($"Barcode = '{_BBarcode}'").
                   FirstOrDefault()
            End If
            ' Change the length as needed...
            If BtxtBarcode.TextLength >= 11 Then
                row = _myTable.
                    Select($"Codeproduct = '{productCode}'").
                    FirstOrDefault()
            Else
                row = _myTable.
                    Select($"Barcode = '{_BBarcode}'").
                   FirstOrDefault()
            End If
            If row IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim qty = If(row("Qty") Is DBNull.Value, 1, row.Field(Of Integer)("Qty"))
                row.SetField("Qty", qty + 1)
                Return
            End If
        End If
        Try
            Dim service = New Itemservice2()
            Dim stock = service.Getitem2(productCode).FirstOrDefault()
            If stock Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown product!")
                Return
            End If
            ' Where does _BBarcode come from?
            _myTable.Rows.Add(_myTable.Rows.Count + 1, productCode,
                                  _BBarcode, stock.Colorcode, 1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

CODE IN FORM2

```
Public Class Form2
   Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    ' A constructor with a parameter...
    Public Sub New(productCode As String)
        Me.New
        ' Moved from Form2_Load event.
        DataGridView1.DataSource = iService.Getitem2(productCode)
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can't believe I'm saying this to you again.  You are missing critical information from your question.  You are asking about moving data between two forms yet shown zero information on how these forms are linked and zero info on the intended data transfer mechanics.  How are these two forms constructed/called. Is there a reference to the instance of one form in the other?

Comment: @Hursey , thanks for your reply. Sorry I'm late to reply. `How are these two forms constructed/called. Is there a reference to the instance of one form in the other?` 
sorry if I didn't explain my posted details and now I've updated if anything is still missing

Comment: Ok, so still a bit light on the detail, so I'm guessing a little here.  I think the main issue based on this bit of code `iService.Getitem2(Form1.Btxtcodeproduct.Text)` is Form1 is the default form instance rather than the actual instance of the form your running in.  You need to provide a reference for the instance of Form1 inside Form2 so it knows where to get the data from.

Comment: This can get into a very broad topic as you may need to consider access modifiers on the controls.  There are some alternative flows you can consider. 1) a possibly global variable of some nature that both forms can see ( you will need to handle the update notifications) 2) Build custom events, the change in one form fires an event, the other form has an event handler listening for it

Comment: What I understand here is that you want to _group by_ `Barcode` or `CodeProduct` and display the result in Form2's grid. No? Other than that, I'm sorry, unable to decode this gibberish. Note, `Form2` in your Form1's context is a _type_ and not an instance of that type. You need to pass the current instance of `Form2` through a parameterized constructor in `Form1` to access its shared/public members. Or the Events approach as mentioned by @Hursey. I know the language barrier makes it difficult for you to clarify. But we need to understand to help. Right?

Comment: @dr.null , `Note, Form2 in your Form1's context is a type and not an instance of that type. You need to pass the current instance of Form2 through a parameterized constructor in Form1 to access its shared/public members. Or the Events approach as mentioned by @Hursey. I know the language barrier makes it difficult for you to clarify. But we need to understand to help. Right?` Because the number of barcode characters is less than 11, I did a manual selection from DataGridView Form2. Thank you reply from you.

Comment: @dr.null ,  I have updated the code in that post I managed to successfully enter the value of DataGridView from Form2 to DataGridView Form1 but the value will increase in DataGridView Form1 if I close Form2. Please guide you. Is there a wrong code method that does it wrong?.

Comment: @Hursey , `I think the main issue based on this bit of code iService.Getitem2(Form1.Btxtcodeproduct.Text) is Form1 is the default form instance rather than the actual instance of the form your running in.` Here there is no problem because in the form1 textbox I use to get a filter with sql where from the product code

Comment: @Hursey ,  I have updated the code in that post I managed to successfully enter the value of DataGridView from Form2 to DataGridView Form1 but the value will increase in DataGridView Form1 if I close Form2.

Comment: Replace `Dim f2 As New Form2` with `Dim f2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).First()`, remove `f2.ShowDialog()` and try.

Comment: @dr.null , thanks for your response but I tried to change your code according to your recommendation but there is an error `Squence contains no elements`

Comment: _Sequence contains no elements_   This probably a completely separate question, maybe worth another post.  But the error is quite self-explanatory, you are simply trying to use a collection that has no elements in it yet.  I'm not 100% sure if this in relation to the suggestion Dr Null made or coming elsewhere in your code.  If from `Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).First()` that would suggest there isn't an instance of Form2 actually running.

Comment: @dr.null , 
Your code runs without problems if I make code like this `Form2.Show()  Dim f2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).First()` am I right to do like this?

Comment: @Hursey , `I'm not 100% sure if this in relation to the suggestion Dr Null made or coming elsewhere in your code. If from Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).First() that would suggest there isn't an instance of Form2 actually running` 
the code from @dr.null runs if i add code like this
`Form2.Show()  Dim f2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).First()`

Comment: `Form2.Show()  Dim f2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).First()`  This really makes no sense, perhaps in the context of a comment your intent is getting lost.  Form2 I'm guessing is a Class, you're referring to it as an object, the difference is really broad, you need to do your own research.  Don't do heaps of code in comments, it's just makes the whole thing hard for us to help.  Either update your question or even better, delete this and post this a COMPLETE question with ALL relevant details

Comment: No son, doing so is wrong as mentioned. That means you don't have an instance of `Form2` running while showing `Form1`. Now, please edit your question and enclose the code within their `Form` classes. Show us the form names. `Public Class Form1 Inherits Form ... End Class` or something else?

Comment: @dr.null , `enclose the code within their Form classes. Show us the form names. Public Class Form1 Inherits Form ... End Class` 
I have updated the form name code in the post, Thank you for your reply

Comment: @dr.null , is there something missing from my code? If it's not enough then I can update my code

Comment: @dr.null , 
thank you that you always guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you are trying in `Form1` to increase the quantities of the products rather than adding new entries. Searching the grid for products either by a valid `Barcode` or `Codeproduct`. But that doesn't work of course if the grid is empty and therefore the `Form2` part comes up. You want to show `Form2`, populate its grid with a `List<Stocks>`, find a product by `Codeproduct` (the Stocks model doesn't contain `Barcode` property), and extract the product's properties from the grid itself.

No, you don't need to do this. You don't need the `Form2` part at all. You have the `Itemservice2` class which exposes the `Getitem2` method which executes a database query to select a recode by the `CodeProduct` field. So, why don't you do that in `Form1` itself?

For example, in `Form1`

```vb
Private _myTable As DataTable

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    _myTable = New DataTable
    _myTable.Columns.AddRange({
        New DataColumn("No", GetType(Integer)),
        New DataColumn("Codeproduct", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Barcode", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("ColorCode", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Qty", GetType(Integer))
    })
    Grid.DataSource = _myTable
End Sub

Private Sub BtxtBarcode_KeyPress(sender As Object,
                                 e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
                                 Handles BtxtBarcode.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
        AddEntry()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddEntry()
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BtxtBarcode.Text) OrElse
       String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BtxtCodeProduct.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter item barcode or product code...", ...
        Return
    End If

    Dim productCode = BtxtCodeProduct.Text.Trim()

    If _myTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Any() Then
        Dim row As DataRow

        ' Change the length as needed...
        If BtxtBarcode.TextLength <> 11 Then
            row = _myTable.
                Select($"Codeproduct = '{productCode}'").
                FirstOrDefault()
        Else
            Dim barcode = BtxtBarcode.Text.Trim()
            row = _myTable.
                Select($"Barcode = '{barcode}'").
                FirstOrDefault()
        End If

        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim qty = If(row("Qty") Is DBNull.Value, 1, row.Field(Of Integer)("Qty"))
            row.SetField("Qty", qty + 1)
            Return
        End If
    End If

    Try
        Dim service = New Itemservice2()
        Dim stock = service.Getitem2(productCode).FirstOrDefault()

        If stock Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown product!")
            Return
        End If

        ' Where does _BBarcode come from?
        _myTable.Rows.Add(_myTable.Rows.Count + 1, productCode,
                          _BBarcode, stock.Colorcode, 1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Note here, when you have a data source, then deal with it to manipulate the data not with the control itself. The control's business is to visualize what's in that data source in a way or another.

Accordingly, we call here the [`DataTable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataTable.Select)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) method to search the `Barcode` or `Codeproduct` fields - if the `DataTable` is not empty - for matches and select the first `DataRow` if any to increase the `Qty` field.

If the `DataTable` is empty or the `Select` method returns nothing for some reason, the next piece of code within the `Try ... End Try` block will run and search the database for that product. If any, you'll get a `Stocks` object, get the required details from it and add a new `DataRow` to your `_myTable`.

---

As for your code snippet, to auto populate the grid of `Form2` when you show it, add a constructor overload that takes a product identifier:

```vb
Public Class Form2 

    ' The default constructor...
    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    ' A constructor with a parameter...
    Public Sub New(productCode As String)
        Me.New
        ' Moved from Form2_Load event.
        DataGridView1.DataSource = iService.Getitem2(productCode)
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
    End Sub

    ' ...etc.
End Class
```

In `Form1`, create a new `Form2` and pass that product code to the constructor. For example:

```vb
Dim productCode = BtxtCodeProduct.Text.Trim()

Using frm = New Form2(productCode)
    If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        ' ...etc.
    End If
End Using
```

`Form2` must return `DialogResult.OK` value to `Form1` to proceed or `DialogResult.Cancel` to `Return` or `Exit Sub`. Add `OK` and `Canel` buttons for that.

```vb
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles btnOK.Click
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
End Sub
```

Now, the `AddEntry` method in `Form1` should be something like this.

```vb
Private Sub AddEntry()
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BtxtBarcode.Text) AndAlso
        String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BtxtCodeProduct.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter item barcode or product code...", ...
        Return
    End If

    Dim productCode = BtxtCodeProduct.Text.Trim()
    Dim _BBarcode = BtxtBarcode.Text.Trim()

    If (_BBarcode.Length < 11) Then
        Using frm = New Form2(productCode)
            If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            ' Get what you want from Form2...
            End If
        End Using
    Else ' _BBarcode.Length >= 11
        Dim row As DataRow = Nothing

        If _myTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Any() Then
            row = _myTable.Select($"Barcode = '{_BBarcode}' Or Codeproduct = '{productCode}'").FirstOrDefault()
        End If

        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim qty = If(row("Qty") Is DBNull.Value, 0, row.Field(Of Integer)("Qty"))
            row.SetField("Qty", qty + 1)
        Else
            ' No matches were found in Form1's grid. What now?
            ' Exit Sub ?
            ' row = _myTable.NewRow and add some values then
            ' _myTable.Rows.Add(row) ?
            ' It's up to you!
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. `Where does _BBarcode come from?` so I have a function method to retrieve the barcode from the class or model item so I can fill the "BtxtBarcode" textbox with a barcode or CodeProduct .

Comment: so why do I need datagridview form2 because there are 2 types namely old barcode or character length 10 this only refers to codeproduct and does not refer to size and ColorCode so then I need to make a selection manually in datagridview form2 then to datagridview form1 while the new barcode or character length is more than 10 then this refers to codeproduct,ColorCode,size so it automatically goes directly to datagridview form1

Comment: `GetItemData(BtxtBarcode.Text)` This method that I use on the barcode textbox can be with codeproduct or also barcode

Comment: `GetItemData(BtxtBarcode.Text)` This method 
came from `GetByCodeProductOrBarcode` 
I just updated the post

Comment: @mbmt Now you are telling me this? This is what you had to mention almost 4 days ago. Now, I'm done here. Understand the example and learn from it what should be done. The old parcode/codeproduct and whatever aren't saved in `Form2`, they are saved in a database and you retrieve them from that database to populate the controls in `Form2`. Which means, you also can do that in `Form1`.

Comment: `Which means, you also can do that in Form1` , Thank you for your reply. sorry I replied late, well I explained actually I use datagridview in form2 for the old barcode as a search pop up so example of the old product with the old barcode "KBE 0927" then we have to choose from the datagridview. So in form1 there is already a main datagridview transaction whose end result will be a save event button to another database. If I use 2 datagridviews in form1 because this will create full space in form1 and also I use it only as a search so the datagridview is not active when the form loads.

Comment: Is there any suggestion from you?

Comment: so the old barcode in the item database only indicates the codeproduct only and so I have to manually select from the stocks database which certainly has a record of more than one old codeproduct but from 3 columns such as CodeProduct, Colorcode, Size this becomes unique.

Comment: @mbmt So, what's wrong with what you already have starting from `Dim f2 As New Form2` ? What's that doesn't work when you show `Form2` and get the values from its grid? Do you errors? Wrong values? Any values at all?

Comment: Thank you for your reply  `what's wrong with what you already have starting from Dim f2 As New Form2 ?` I haven't done it yet First I have to call form2 from your code `If BtxtBarcode.TextLength >= 11 Then` If less than 11 then Form2 Show appears

Comment: `If BtxtBarcode.TextLength < 11 Then  Dim f2 As New Form2 f2.Show() End If` In which position should I use this code in your code please guide.

Comment: Thanks updates from you to show form2. `BtxtBarcode.TextLength < 11` for old barcode then show form2 and `BtxtBarcode.TextLength >= 11` for new barcode without show form2 How do I adapt this code to your code.

Comment: `If BtxtBarcode.TextLength <= 10 Then  Using frm = New Form2(productCode)  If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then End If  End Using row = _myTable.Select($"Codeproduct = '{productCode}'").FirstOrDefault() Else row = _myTable. Select($"Barcode = '{_BBarcode}'").FirstOrDefault() End If` after code `If BtxtBarcode.TextLength >= 11 Then etc` But he doesn't show Form2 for BtxtBarcode.TextLength <= 10 and directly adds rows to the DataGridView. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I have updated the code in the post according to your request

Comment: because the old barcode then I have to select from form2 datagridview then the value to datagriview form1

Comment: thanks for the updated answer from you made it run perfect

Comment: I have a recent post maybe you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76751435/why-is-my-first-load-form2-containing-no-record-in-datagridview-in-vb-net