# Why is my first load form2 containing no record in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

The first time I did a key event enter, first form2 did not show a record in datagrdiview but I closed form2 then I did a key event enter again then a record appeared in datagridview form2. Is there something wrong with my code? and attached gif file below.

```vb
Private Sub GetItemData(ByVal iditem As String)
    Dim Item = iService.GetByCodeProductOrBarcode(iditem)
    If Item IsNot Nothing Then
        If String.Equals(iditem, Item.Barcode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            BtxtBarcode.Text = Item.Barcode
        ElseIf String.Equals(iditem, Item.CodeProduct, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            BtxtBarcode.Text = Item.CodeProduct
        End If
        Btxtcodeproduct.Text = Item.CodeProduct
    Else
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub BtxtBarcode_KeyPress(sender As Object,
                                 e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
                                 Handles BtxtBarcode.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
        AddEntry()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddEntry()
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BtxtBarcode.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter item barcode or product code...")
        Return
    End If
    Dim productCode = Btxtcodeproduct.Text.Trim()
    Dim _BBarcode = BtxtBarcode.Text.Trim()
    If (_BBarcode.Length <= 11) Then
        GetItemData(_BBarcode)
        Using frm = New Form2(productCode)
            If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
                If _myTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Any() Then
                    row = If(_myTable.
                    Select($"Barcode = '{_BBarcode}'").
                        FirstOrDefault(), _myTable.
                        Select($"Codeproduct = '{productCode}'").
                        FirstOrDefault())
                End If
                If row IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim qty = If(row("Qty") Is DBNull.Value, 0, row.Field(Of Integer)("Qty"))
                    row.SetField("Qty", qty + 1)
                    Return
                Else
                    '...etc.
                End If
                Try
                    Dim service = New Itemservice2()
                    Dim stock = service.Getitem2(productCode).FirstOrDefault()
                    If stock Is Nothing Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Unknown product!")
                        Return
                    End If
                    For Each row2 As DataGridViewRow In frm.DataGridView1.Rows
                        Dim isselect As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row2.Cells("checkboxcolumn").Value)
                        If isselect Then
                            _myTable.Rows.Add(_myTable.Rows.Count + 1, frm.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString,
                                              _BBarcode, frm.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value, 1)
                            BtxtBarcode.Clear()
                            Btxtcodeproduct.Clear()
                        End If
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        End Using
    ElseIf _BBarcode.Length >= 12 Then
        'etc
End Sub
```

form2 load process

[image]

Comment: Reset the `productCode` and `_BBarcode` variables after calling `GetItemData(_BBarcode)` which changes the values of the text boxes.

Comment: @dr.null , thanks your reply. You mean reset the variable how can I do it please guide from you

Comment: `productCode = Btxtcodeproduct.Text.Trim()`, `_BBarcode = BtxtBarcode.Text.Trim()` before `Using frm = New Form2(productCode) ...`

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you guide from you it went very perfectly

Comment: @dr.null , You can answer as answer so I can mark your answer directly

Comment: Thank you but I'm little busy here. Feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @dr.null , 
sorry to disturb your time `row = If(_myTable.Select($"Barcode = '{_BBarcode}'").FirstOrDefault(), _myTable.Select($"Codeproduct = '{productCode}'").FirstOrDefault())` 
if I want to add variables or datatable columns in the code, how can I do that please guide me

Comment: `row = _myTable.Select($"Barcode = '{_BBarcode}' Or Codeproduct = '{productCode}' Or OtherField = '{OtherVariable}'").FirstOrDefault()`. Just like what the gentlemen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76754254/14171304) told you. Btw, no need to create new accounts to ask new questions. Not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per guidelines from @dr.null

```
  GetItemData(BtxtBarcode.Text)
  Dim productCode = Btxtcodeproduct.Text.Trim()
  Dim _BBarcode = BtxtBarcode.Text.Trim()
```