# how to use cellendedit in multi column datagridview with multi oledb command in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, oledb, oledbcommand, executereader

I'm trying to use cellendedit in multi column datagridview with multi oledb command in vb.net

I tried the code below it doesn't produce anything in datagridview and if I use only one datagridview column with one oledb command then it appears in datagridview.

I have the code below, but this is still wrong.

please guide me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader
    Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader
    Dim dr3 As OleDbDataReader
    Public Function GetConnectionString2() As String
        Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        Return strCon
    End Function
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("CODEPRODUCT") AndAlso DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("SIZEPRODUCT") Then
            Using _conn As New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString2)
                Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("select * from [PRODUCT] where CODEPRODUCT='" & DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CODEPRODUCT").Value.ToString() & "'", _conn)
                    Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("select * from [SIZEPRODUCT] where SIZEPRODUCT='" & DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("SIZEPRODUCT").Value.ToString() & "'", _conn)
                        Using cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("select * from [COLORCODE] where COLORCODE='" & DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLORCODE").Value.ToString() & "'", _conn)
                            Try
                                _conn.Open()
                                dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
                                dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                                dr3 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                                dr1.Read()
                                dr2.Read()
                                dr3.Read()
                                If dr1.HasRows AndAlso dr2.HasRows AndAlso dr3.HasRows Then
                                    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DESCRIPTION").Value = dr1.Item("DESCRIPTION")
                                    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CATEGORY").Value = dr2.Item("CATEGORY")
                                    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLORNAME").Value = dr3.Item("COLORNAME")
                                Else
                                    MsgBox("Not found")
                                End If
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                            End Try
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Update code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Using _conn As New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString2)
If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("CODEPRODUCT") OrElse DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("SIZEPRODUCT") OrElse DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("COLORCODE") Then
                Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("select * from [PRODUCT] where CODEPRODUCT='" & DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CODEPRODUCT").Value.ToString() & "'", _conn)
                    'Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("select * from [SIZEPRODUCT] where SIZEPRODUCT='" & DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("SIZEPRODUCT").Value.ToString() & "'", _conn)
                    'Using cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("select * from [COLORCODE] where COLORCODE='" & cstr(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLORCODE").Value).ToString() & "'", _conn)
                    Try
                        _conn.Open()
                        dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
                        'dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                        'dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader
                        If dr1.Read OrElse dr2.Read OrElse dr3.Read Then
                            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DESCRIPTION").Value = dr1.Item("DESCRIPTION")
                            ''DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CATEGORY").Value = dr2.Item("CATEGORY")
                            'DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLORNAME").Value = dr3.Item("COLORNAME")
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Not found")
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End Using
                'End Using
                ''End Using
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

[image: screenshot DATAGRIDVIEW]

Comment: OT, you don't need to nest all those `Using` blocks. You can use a single `Using` statement and just put a comma between variable declarations. That will make your code more readable. You only need nested blocks if you need to put code between them.

Comment: Why are you testing `HasRows` after calling `Read`? There's no point doing both. `Read` will return the same value as `HasRows` and you need to call it so just use `Read` in the `If` block. Also, you should be closing all your data readers. Ideally, you'd do that with a `Using` block.

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT *` in your queries when you only want one column? Don't retrieve data that you know you don't need. If you only need a single value then you should be calling `ExecuteScalar`, not `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: As for the issue, you need to debug your code. You're a developer so use your development tools. You're not a user so you don't just watch the UI like a user would. Debug the code properly, using breakpoints, and you'll probably be able to fix the issue yourself. If not, at least you can tell us what actually happened and how it differs from your expectations.

Comment: Finally, don't use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code. Learn how to use parameters and make your code better and safer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `OT, you don't need to nest all those Using blocks. You can use a single Using statement and just put a comma between variable declarations. That will make your code more readable. You only need nested blocks if you need to put code between them.` thank you for your response, please guide me

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Why are you testing HasRows after calling Read? There's no point doing both. Read will return the same value as HasRows and you need to call it so just use Read in the If block. Also, you should be closing all your data readers. Ideally, you'd do that with a Using block. –`  so I don't need to use `HasRows`

Comment: `If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("CODEPRODUCT") AndAlso DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("SIZEPRODUCT") Then ...` ! How could that be possible? Perhaps you mean `OrElse` rather than `AndAlso`? Please provide the relevant details. Bound/Unbound grid? Bound to what type? Field/Column types?

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your reply. `Bound/Unbound grid? Bound to what type? Field/Column types?` `Bound grid and field/column type data text/string and column type datagridview textbox column

Comment: @dr.null , 
I have updated the code in the post but still I can only use `cmd1`

Comment: You can run a single query to select fields from different tables and return a single row that contains their values. Still, what you are trying to do here does not make sense. Based on the logic shown, it makes more sense if you get `DESCRIPTION` from `PRODUCT` table when the value of the `CodeProduct` cell changes. And get `CATEGORY` from `SIZEPRODUCT` table when the value of the `SizeProduct` cell changes. The same applies to the `ColorCode` cell. No?

Comment: @dr.null , yes you are right `You can run a single query to select fields from different tables and return a single row that contains their values` please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea here is to run the three queries **only** when the user enters/selects all the required and correct identifiers of the three tables, then you can execute just one query instead of three to select the required fields from the three tables.

Assuming unbound grid, the fishy table and field names are correct, and parameters value of type `String`. You could write for example:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim KeyCols = {"CodeProduct", "SizeProduct", "ColorCode"}
    Dim ValueCols = {"Description", "Category", "ColorName"}

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso KeyCols.Any(Function(col) col = dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name) Then
        Dim dict = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells.OfType(Of DataGridViewTextBoxCell).
        Where(Function(cell) KeyCols.Any(Function(col) col = cell.OwningColumn.Name)).
        ToDictionary(Function(cell) cell.OwningColumn.Name, Function(cell) cell.Value)

        If dict.Values.Any(Function(v) v Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.ToString())) Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim sql =
        <sql>
            SELECT Product.Description, SizeProduct.Category, ColorCode.ColorName
            FROM Product, SizeProduct, ColorCode
            WHERE Product.CodeProduct = ?
            AND SizeProduct.SizeProduct = ?
            AND ColorCode.ColorCode = ?
        </sql>.Value

        Using con = New OleDbConnection("..."), cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(
            dict.Select(Function(kvp) New OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarWChar) With {
                .Value = kvp.Value
            }).ToArray())

            con.Open()

            Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If rdr.Read() Then
                    For Each col In ValueCols
                        dgv(col, e.RowIndex).Value = rdr(col)
                    Next
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("one or more wrong identifiers.")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Note here, this query will return a single record to read **only** if all the passed `CodeProduct`, `SizeProduct`, and `ColorCode` identifiers are valid. The alternative - as noted - is to run a separate query for each table when you get the related id/code changed in the grid.

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex < 0 Then Return
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim row = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim arrQueries() = {
        New With {
            .KeyCell = row.Cells("CodeProduct"),
            .ValueCell = row.Cells("Description"),
            .Table = "Product"},
        New With {
            .KeyCell = row.Cells("SizeProduct"),
            .ValueCell = row.Cells("Category"),
            .Table = "SizeProduct"},
        New With {
            .KeyCell = row.Cells("ColorCode"),
            .ValueCell = row.Cells("ColorName"),
            .Table = "ColorCode"}
    }

    If Not arrQueries.Any(
        Function(q) q.KeyCell.OwningColumn Is dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)) Then
        Return
    End If

    Using con = New OleDbConnection("..."), cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        con.Open()
        For Each q In arrQueries
            If q.KeyCell.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                q.KeyCell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso
                Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(q.KeyCell.Value.ToString()) Then
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                    "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = ?",
                    q.ValueCell.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName,
                    q.Table,
                    q.KeyCell.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName)
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = q.KeyCell.Value
                q.ValueCell.Value = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            Else
                q.ValueCell.Value = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have an error , `dgv(kvp.Key, e.RowIndex).Value = rdr(kvp.Key)` this line code and `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: CODEPRODUCT`

Comment: @siwa86 Right, bug fixed. Try now and double check the names.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Sorry I was late in replying because previously my laptop was damaged. can it stay in the datagridview row until the identifiers are valid?

Comment: @siwa86 Glad to know you're OK. I don't understand your question. The query will run only if all the three inputs are provided by the user. If you want to get them separately, then execute separate queries for each column.

Comment: So what I mean is that if one of the identifiers columns are not valid then it remains in the relevant column until the identifiers are valid

Comment: @siwa86 Yes, try now.

Comment: perfect and after filling in 3 `Value Cells` I tried to edit the previous one again, can one of the columns be blank if the identifiers are not valid?

Comment: @siwa86 You can clear first the **Value** cells if their corresponding **Key** cells are Nothing or empty. So, if the `CodeProduct` cell value of the current row is nothing/empty,  set the `Description` cell value to `Nothing`. The same for the other two columns.

Comment: thank you for your response, in which position should I put the code please guide me

Comment: @siwa86 I Recommend the second option. Give it a go.

Comment: thanks for your response to the second option but I tried ValueCell does not appear if there is something wrong please guide you.

Comment: @siwa86 Right, delete `If Not dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty Then Return`. Also, double check your columns name because they map to their corresponding database fields in this example.

Comment: after delete `If Not dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty Then Return` 
went very perfectly

Comment: @siwa86 OK. It's better to move this code as is to the `CellValueChanged` event to avoid the redundant and unnecessary calls.

Comment: `It's better to move this code as is to the CellValueChanged event to avoid the redundant and unnecessary calls` 
thank you, I moved to the event according to your recommendation and how can I force the user to fill in until it is valid then they can move to the next row and cell?

Comment: @siwa86 [DataGridView.CellValidating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating?view=windowsdesktop-8.0).

Comment: I posted the latest one related to your answer, maybe you can help me . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555824/why-doesnt-cellvaluechanged-immediately-appear-in-the-expression-datatable-colu)

Comment: `DataGridView.CellValidating.` thank you for your info

Comment: Instead of handling the `DataGridView.CellValidating` event, right after the `q.ValueCell.Value = cmd.ExecuteScalar()` line, set the `q.KeyCell.Value = Nothing` if the `q.ValueCell.Value` is `DbNull.Value`. Which means the user has entered a wrong key. Does that make sense?

Comment: `if q.valuecell is DBnull.value then q.keycell.value = nothing` Do you mean this way means the user has entered a wrong key.

Comment: I want to ask if the column name DataGridView is different from the field name in the database how can I solve it in `KeyCell` and `ValueCell` please guide me .I like your answer code recommendations and also you set it very simple

Comment: @siwa86 See the edit. Move everything back to the `CellEndEdit` event. Mixed up with your other questions.

Comment: if I move to `CellEndEdit` event 
then I use this code `DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).EndEdit()` then there is an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` but if I use `CellValueChanged` event then there are no errors

Comment: @siwa86 No it does not unless you're doing something elsewhere that could cause this exception. Anyways, Add null check just in case: `DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)?.EndEdit()`.

Comment: `DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)?.EndEdit()` 
Thank you for your response, problem solved.

Comment: for this `if q.valuecell is DBnull.value then q.keycell.value = nothing` Should I use the DataGridView.CellValidating event so that until the user enters validly it can continue to another column or to another cell. Please Guide me. Btw 
I have a recent post related to your answer which is data column expression maybe you can help me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77561377/why-is-the-datatable-expression-column-become-ready-only-in-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment136736813_77561377)

Comment: @siwa86 Well, you can implement the `CellValidating` event to do so. It depends on how you validate the inputs and how you update the database.

Comment: thank you for your response . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76575084/how-to-add-different-colour-icons-images-automatic-to-the-row-header-of-a-datagr/76582349#76582349) 
I am interested in the answer from this link but I have an error because I combined the answer in this post with the answer from the link, so I will make a new post, hopefully you can help me

Comment: sorry, fine I'll delete it