# why doesn't CellValueChanged immediately appear in the expression datatable column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, datacolumn

I'm trying to use CellValueChanged but why doesn't CellValueChanged immediately appear in the expression datatable column (MATERIALCOLORNAME) in vb.net

I have the code below

please guide me

Thanks

```
Private Sub CreateDataTable()
    If m_DataTable IsNot Nothing Then Return
    m_DataTable = New DataTable
    'Columns
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("CODEPRODUCT", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("COLORCODE", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("COLORNAME", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("MATERIAL", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("MATERIALCOLORNAME", GetType(String), "TRIM(IIF(MATERIAL Is Null Or SUBSTRING(MATERIAL, 1, 1) = '-', '', MATERIAL) + IIF(COLORNAME Is Null Or SUBSTRING(COLORNAME, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + COLORNAME))")
End Sub
```

this is the code I use :

```
 Public m_DataTable As DataTable
 Public Function GetConnectionString2() As String
        Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        Return strCon
    End Function

  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex < 0 Then Return
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        'If Not dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty Then Return
        Dim row = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim arrQueries() = {
            New With {
                .KeyCell = row.Cells("CODEPRODUCT"),
                .ValueCell = row.Cells("DESCRIPTION"),
                .Table = "PRODUCT"},
            New With {
                .KeyCell = row.Cells("SIZEPRODUCT"),
                .ValueCell = row.Cells("CATEGORY"),
                .Table = "SIZEPRODUCT"},
            New With {
                .KeyCell = row.Cells("COLORCODE"),
                .ValueCell = row.Cells("COLORNAME"),
                .Table = "COLORCODE"},
            New With {
                .KeyCell = row.Cells("COLORCODE"),
                .ValueCell = row.Cells("MATERIAL"),
                .Table = "COLORCODE"}
        }
        If Not arrQueries.Any(
            Function(q) q.KeyCell.OwningColumn Is dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)) Then
            Return
        End If
        Using con = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString2()), cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            con.Open()
            For Each q In arrQueries
                If q.KeyCell.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                    q.KeyCell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso
                    Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(q.KeyCell.Value.ToString()) Then
                    cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                        "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = ?",
                        q.ValueCell.OwningColumn.Name, q.Table, q.KeyCell.OwningColumn.Name)
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = q.KeyCell.Value
                    q.ValueCell.Value = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                Else
                    q.ValueCell.Value = Nothing
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateDataTable()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = m_DataTable
    End Sub
```

this is a gif of the cellvaluechanged process

[image: CellValueChanged]

Comment: Please explain, in words, exactly what you're doing, what you expect to happen, what actually happens and exactly how the two differ. The video is good but it's not a substitute for an actual explanation.

Comment: It might be worth handling some events of your `DataTable` in your debugging. I suspect that the calculated column is not updated until the `RowChanged` event is raised, rather than when the `ColumnChanged` event is raised. That's an educated guess. If you bind via a `BindingSource`, which you should, it might be that calling the `EndEdit` method after each cell change will force it, but I suspect not. Calling `Validate` on the form might force it too. Again, that's a bit of a guess.

Comment: It gonna work if you hit `Enter` or select different row to commit and end the edit operation of the current row so the underlying data source get the changes and the expression column updates the value. The base class does not process the Tab key hits as such. After `Dim row = ...`, call `DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row.EndEdit()`.

Comment: Just `DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).EndEdit()`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,  `Please explain, in words, exactly what you're doing, what you expect to happen, what actually happens and exactly how the two differ. The video is good but it's not a substitute for an actual explanation.` sorry if the explanation is not very clear in this post

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,  `Calling Validate on the form might force it too. Again, that's a bit of a guess.` Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @dr.null ,   `DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).EndEdit()` Your advice goes perfectly. ` You can answer as a question so I directly mark your answer