# why is the datatable expression column become ready only in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, expression, datacolumn

I'm trying to so I want to use the datatable expression column to print labels so below I made a simple example of moving with a checkbox from datagridview1 to datagridview2

I have the code below, but this is still wrong.

please guide me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Public dt As DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("A", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("B", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(String), "TRIM(IIF(A Is Null Or SUBSTRING(A, 1, 1) = '-', '', A) + IIF(B Is Null Or SUBSTRING(B, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + B))")
        dt.Rows.Add("BALOTELLY", "OLD WARDAH (02)")
        dt.Rows.Add("TOYOBO FODU THOMPSON", "LIGHT BLACK (12)")
        dt.Rows.Add("MCR", "-")
        dt.Rows.Add("WALLY COTTON CREAP", "-")
        dt.Rows.Add("WALLY COTTON CREAP", "BLACK (23)")
        dt.Rows.Add("-", "-")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Dim CheckedBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        CheckedBoxColumn.Width = 40
        CheckedBoxColumn.Name = "checkboxcolumn"
        CheckedBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Check"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, CheckedBoxColumn)
End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each row2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim isselect As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row2.Cells("checkboxcolumn").Value)
            If isselect Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next row2
        Dim selectedRows As DataTable = dt.Clone
        For Each row2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim isselect As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row2.Cells("checkboxcolumn").Value)
            If isselect Then
                Dim newRow As DataRow = selectedRows.Rows.Add()
                newRow("A") = dt.Rows(row2.Index)("A")
                newRow("B") = dt.Rows(row2.Index)("B")
'error below line code "Column "C" is ready only
                newRow("C") = dt.Rows(row2.Index)("C")
            End If
        Next row2
        DataGridView2.DataSource = selectedRows
        'theLabel.DataSource = selectedRows
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide the error message as text, formatted appropriately. Screenshots can be helpful but are NEVER enough on there own. All text should be text, not pictures alone.

Comment: Of course that column is read-only. You have specifically stated that the values in that column are calculated based on an expression and values in other columns. If you assigned a value directly, that would contradict the expression. You can't have it both ways. Either the values are calculated internally or they are set externally.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Sorry if my explanation is not perfect, I just updated the code where the error code line is

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `You can't have it both ways. Either the values are calculated internally or they are set externally.` Please guide me so I can solve the problem

Comment: There is no problem to solve. Either use an expression and have it read-only or don't.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , 
I have updated the code in the post according to your recommendation but the error still appears. `Column "C" is ready only`

Comment: OMG, you're not reading what I'm writing. You are still setting the `Expression` property of the column. Read the words! If you set the `Expression` then the values are calculated internally and you can only read them. If you want to set them externally then you cannot use an expression. I won't repeat myself again.

Comment: `selectedRows.Columns("C").Expression = Nothing : selectedRows.Columns("C").ReadOnly = False`.

Comment: @dr.null , 
Thank you very much
Your answer went absolutely perfectly , 
I put your code after this code `Dim selectedRows As DataTable = dt.Clone` then your code `selectedRows.Columns("C").Expression = Nothing : selectedRows.Columns("C").ReadOnly = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the perfect answer from @dr.null

I thank you for the help

```
      Dim selectedRows As DataTable = dt.Clone
selectedRows.Columns("C").Expression = Nothing : selectedRows.Columns("C").ReadOnly = False
```