# How to resolve the StackOverflowException error in datagridview endedit in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to resolve the StackOverflowException error in datagridview endedit with VB.NET.

If I go back to the cell before making the edit, the error appears.

please guide me

Based on link [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77436304/how-to-use-cellendedit-in-multi-column-datagridview-with-multi-oledb-command-in/77447095?noredirect=1#comment136737614_77447095)

and

[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76575084/how-to-add-different-colour-icons-images-automatic-to-the-row-header-of-a-datagr/76582349#76582349)

Thanks

I have the code below, Maybe still wrong :

```
Public Class Form1
  Private bmp As Bitmap
  Public m_DataTable As DataTable

  Public Function GetConnectionString2() As String
    Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Return strCon
  End Function

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    'To reduce the flickering...
    DataGridView1.GetType().
    GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).
    SetValue(DataGridView1, True)
    'Collect dark colors...
    colors = GetType(Color).
    GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).
    Where(Function(pi) pi.PropertyType = GetType(Color)).
    Select(Function(pi) CType(pi.GetValue(GetType(Color), Nothing), Color)).
    Where(Function(c)
              Return ((
          c.R * 0.299F +
          c.G * 0.587F +
          c.B * 0.114F) / 256.0F) <= 0.5F
          End Function).ToArray()
    bmp = My.Resources.Resources.money
  End Sub

  Private Sub CreateDataTable()
    If m_DataTable IsNot Nothing Then Return
    m_DataTable = New DataTable
    'Columns
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("CODEPRODUCT", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("COLORCODE", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("COLORNAME", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("MATERIAL", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("MATERIALCOLORNAME", GetType(String), "TRIM(IIF(MATERIAL Is Null Or SUBSTRING(MATERIAL, 1, 1) = '-', '', MATERIAL) + IIF(COLORNAME Is Null Or SUBSTRING(COLORNAME, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + COLORNAME))")
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("INFO", GetType(String))
    m_DataTable.Columns.Add("QTY", GetType(Integer))
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CreateDataTable()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = m_DataTable
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateColorIndices()
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    Dim groups = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
    Where(Function(r) r.Index <> DataGridView1.NewRowIndex).
    GroupBy(Function(r) New With {
    Key .Col0 = r.Cells("CODEPRODUCT").Value,
            Key .Col1 = r.Cells("COLORCODE").Value,
                            Key .Col2 = r.Cells("SIZEPRODUCT").Value
            })
    For i = 0 To groups.Count - 1
        Dim index = i Mod colors.Length
        For Each row In groups(i)
            row.Tag = index
        Next
    Next
    DataGridView1.Invalidate()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Grid_CellValueChanged(sender As Object,
            e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    UpdateColorIndices()
  End Sub

  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) _
       Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = -1 AndAlso
    e.RowIndex <> DataGridView1.NewRowIndex Then

        Dim ellipseSize = DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height - 32
        Dim ellipseRect = New Drawing.Rectangle(
            e.CellBounds.X + (e.CellBounds.Width - ellipseSize) \ 2,
            e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height - ellipseSize) \ 2,
            ellipseSize, ellipseSize)
        Dim imgSize = ellipseSize
        Dim imgRect = New Drawing.Rectangle(
        ellipseRect.X + (ellipseRect.Width - imgSize) \ 2,
        ellipseRect.Y + (ellipseRect.Height - imgSize) \ 2,
        imgSize, imgSize)
        Dim colorIndex = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Tag)
        Dim g = e.Graphics
        Dim gs = g.Save()

        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background Or
            DataGridViewPaintParts.Border Or
            DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground)

        Using ellipseBrush = New SolidBrush(colors(colorIndex))
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
            g.FillEllipse(ellipseBrush, ellipseRect)
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            g.DrawImage(bmp, imgRect, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End Using

        g.Restore(gs)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex < 0 Then Return
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    'If Not dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty Then Return
    Dim row = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)?.EndEdit()
    Dim arrQueries() = {
        New With {
            .KeyCell = row.Cells("CODEPRODUCT"),
            .ValueCell = row.Cells("DESCRIPTION"),
            .Table = "PRODUCT"},
        New With {
            .KeyCell = row.Cells("SIZEPRODUCT"),
            .ValueCell = row.Cells("CATEGORY"),
            .Table = "SIZEPRODUCT"},
        New With {
            .KeyCell = row.Cells("COLORCODE"),
            .ValueCell = row.Cells("COLORNAME"),
            .Table = "COLORCODE"},
        New With {
            .KeyCell = row.Cells("COLORCODE"),
            .ValueCell = row.Cells("MATERIAL"),
            .Table = "COLORCODE"}
    }
    If Not arrQueries.Any(
        Function(q) q.KeyCell.OwningColumn Is dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)) Then
        Return
    End If
    Using con = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString2()), cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        con.Open()
        For Each q In arrQueries
            If q.KeyCell.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                q.KeyCell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso
                Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(q.KeyCell.Value.ToString()) Then
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                    "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = ?",
                q.ValueCell.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName,
                q.Table,
                q.KeyCell.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName)
                'q.ValueCell.OwningColumn.Name, q.Table, q.KeyCell.OwningColumn.Name)
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = q.KeyCell.Value
                q.ValueCell.Value = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                'If q.ValueCell Is DBNull.Value Then

                '    q.KeyCell.Value = Nothing
                'End If
            Else
                q.ValueCell.Value = Nothing

            End If
        Next
    End Using
  End Sub
End Class
```

[image: System.StackOverflowException]

Comment: StackOverflow probably means you have re-entrant code somewhere.

Comment: @SSS ,thank you for your reply . What do you mean, I have to call the code again

Comment: If you edit a cell in the `CellEndEdit` event handler then you're going to cause that event to be raised again... and again, and again,... until the stack overflows. Don't do something in an event handler that causes the same event to be raised again unless you have some conditional code that will stop the chain from continuing indefinitely. Issues like this are usually a failure of logic, so you should go back and look at your logic first and make sure that it's not circular. If it's not then the code mustn't faithfully implement that logic.

Comment: jmcilhinney explained it well. You have code somewhere that calls itself and gets in an infinite loop

Comment: Comment `DataGridView1.EndEdit()`. in `UpdateColorIndices`. The [first option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76582349/14171304) is more convenient to combine. You already have a `DataTable` with some additional and expression columns. So, add one more to keep the image index and hide its grid column.

Comment: @dr.null , thank you for your reply. `Comment DataGridView1.EndEdit()` 
If I comment the code it won't be a problem if I keep using the second option