# How to reset BindingSource/BindingList sequence number in DataGridView with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource, bindinglist

I'm trying to reset BindingSource/BindingList sequence number in DataGridView with VB.NET.

or something went wrong in my code implementation

Please Guide Me.

Below I attach screenshots and codes as well

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private Function GetProduct() As Product
        Return If(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 0, Nothing, TryCast(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).OwningRow.DataBoundItem, Product))
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim list = New List(Of Product)() From {
    New Product With {
        .No = 1,
        .Codeproduct = "1000",
        .Qty = 20,
        .Qty_Stock = 50
    },
    New Product With {
            .No = 2,
        .Codeproduct = "2000",
        .Qty = 30,
        .Qty_Stock = 40
    },
     New Product With {
            .No = 3,
        .Codeproduct = "3000",
        .Qty = 30,
        .Qty_Stock = 40
    }
}

 bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Product)(CType(list, IList(Of Product)))}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource
        DataGridView1.Columns("No").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Codeproduct").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Qty").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Qty_Stock").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Coldel").ReadOnly = True
 End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("Coldel") Then
            If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
                Return
            End If
            If MessageBox.Show("Delete selected record?", "CONFIRM!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                Dim product = GetProduct()
                Dim bs = TryCast(bindingSource.DataSource, BindingList(Of Product))
                'do method service sql to database
                bs.Remove(product)
                DataGridView1.Refresh()

'update code 
  Dim counter As Integer = 0
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    counter += 1
                    'row.Cells("No").Value = counter
row.Cells("No").Value = If(row.Index = DataGridView1.NewRowIndex, Nothing, counter)
                Next row
                'do method service sql save to database




            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Before Delete `No` 2
[image]

after Delete `No` 2
[image]

So in the results want number 3 to be number 2

[image: After update code]

[image: After update code-2]

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in your code that makes any attempt to do that, so nothing went wrong. You have to actually do something for it to not work, and you've done nothing. Until you actually do something, there's no problem for us to help you with.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , 
Sorry I'm late replying and just now I've updated the code in the post and also the Gif file, but the problem for `No` 3 will disappear if I move Row. Please guide from you

Comment: `row.Cells("No").Value = If(row.Index = DataGridView1.NewRowIndex, Nothing, counter)`. Do you have a database field for this? Hope not. Better to get rid of this column and the corresponding db field if any and handle the `CellPainting` event to draw the row number on the row headers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76573877/14171304) for example, draw string instead of image.

Comment: @dr.null , thank you for your reply. Sorry I'm late replying and just now I've updated the code in the post and also the Gif file, but why is the last row the value `0` in the `No` column but will disappear if I move Row. `Do you have a database field for this?` 
Yes, I have that database field as a sequence of item details from one transaction number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new grid row displays the default value of the data-bound object. For reference types, the new row displays nothing if the value is nothing, or it displays the value of the column [DefaultCellStyle.NullValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle?view=netframework-4.8) property if you want to provide a default value rather than `Nothing`/`DbNull`.

For the value types like your `No` column, the data-bound item is of type `Integer`, so, the new row displays the default value of that type, `0`. No, you can't use here the `NullValue` property to change that.

To hide the default value `0` in the `No` column, you have two options. Either convert the property to nullable integer in the model:

```vb
Public Class Product
    Public Property No As Integer?
    ' ...
End Class
```

Or set the [DefaultCellStyle.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.Format)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to hide the zero values. The `#` format specifier for example. See [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) for more.

```vb
DataGridView1.Columns("No").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#"
```

---

**Side Notes**

▶ You can replace this:

```vb
bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Product)(CType(list, IList(Of Product)))}
```

With:

```vb
bindingSource = New BindingSource(New BindingList(Of Product)(list), Nothing)
```

▶ You can simplify the `CellContentClick` event:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso
    dgv.Columns("ColDel") Is dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Then
        Dim item = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, Product)
        If item IsNot Nothing AndAlso
            MessageBox.Show("Confirm ...", "App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim i = 1
            Dim bs = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource)
            bs.Remove(item)
            For Each row As Product In bs
                row.No = i
                i += 1
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is perfect . in your code where I put the delete service method to the database and the update service method to the database, please guide me

Comment: @siwa86 What delete and update services? Where are they in your question? New requirements? Anyway, you should update the database when you click some `OK` button of a data entry Form to insert/update/delete and close the Form. I don't know about your design. Doing that as you delete/update/insert is not a good approach. Leave a space to reject the changes by clicking some `Cancel` button.

Comment: ,actually almost the same as my post which is closed at this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768208/how-to-check-whether-the-qty-is-used-for-sales-or-not-to-make-a-minus-stock-befo) . According to your code then for the service delete it to the database `bs.Remove(item)` before this line code I use  `PIservice.DeletePurchase(Invono) &  PIservice.Deletepurchasedetail(Invono) and service update stock`

Comment: and service update `No` after your code `Next` . in cell content only perform 2 actions, delete/update. `Leave a space to reject the changes by clicking some Cancel button.` for this code `MessageBox.Show("Confirm ...", "App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then` 
Is it enough for rejection? If I select `No` then no action will occur

Comment: @siwa86 The closed question has different requirements, I can't include it in my answer. Some guidelines are: 1) Get the item `Dim item = TryCast(...`. 2) Query the db and create the model that contains the quantities. 3) Do the math for the selected product, if the quantity - 1 < 0, show a message box to alert the user and `Return`. 4) If >= 0, show a message box to confirm the deletion and delete the related records from the db, update the `No` table, and that's it all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For the closed questions I make a new question, please help and guide me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77773340/how-to-use-linq-looping-to-check-calculations-that-generate-minus-stock-before-d)